# Updating embed message doesnt work - discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I'm making a very detailed RPG system in my discord bot. For now I'm creating a tower command which lets you play through stages of the tower and fight against different types of enemies. The problem is that I have no idea why editing an embed message doesn't work, it should update your´s and HP of the enemy depending on how much the enemy hit you. It works with normal message where it updates DMG that the enemy gave you, but not with embed message, any ideas? I really hope there is some solution, because I don't want to change it completely to only simple message, that wouldn't look great.

Here is how it looks in discord chat, the embed message doesn't update the HP of the troll or the player, it works only with the normal message under the embed one.

[image]

Code: (the only lines of code that should be important for you start from the embed message but I included the whole code just to be more specific).

````py
# Tower
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 100.0, commands.BucketType.user)
async def tower(msg):
    await open_rpg(msg.author)
    user = msg.author
    users = await rpg_data()

    question= await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " Do you really wish to enter the tower? `yes` `no`")
    def checkyn(message):
        return message.content in ["yes", "no"]

    while True:
        answer = await bot.wait_for("message", check=checkyn)
        if answer.author.id == msg.author.id:
            break

    if answer.content == "no":
        await answer.delete()
        await msg.message.delete()
        await question.delete()
        return

    names= ["nothing","Troll","Lion","Fish"......]

    battle = users[str(user.id)]["battle-active"]
    if battle == 1:
        await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " You are currently fighting!")
        tower.reset_cooldown(msg)
        return

    users[str(msg.author.id)]["battle-active"] += 1
    with open("rpg.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    coins = users[str(user.id)]["coins"]
    mages = users[str(user.id)]["mages"]
    guardians = users[str(user.id)]["guardians"]
    hunters = users[str(user.id)]["hunters"]
    defense = users[str(user.id)]["defense"]
    power = users[str(user.id)]["power"]
    rpoints = users[str(user.id)]["rpoints"]
    hunger = users[str(user.id)]["hunger"]
    armor = users[str(user.id)]["armor"]
    shield = users[str(user.id)]["shield"]
    sword = users[str(user.id)]["sword"]
    sword_durability = users[str(user.id)]["sword-durability"]
    shield_durability = users[str(user.id)]["shield-durability"]
    armor_durability = users[str(user.id)]["armor-durability"]
    shield_defense = users[str(user.id)]["shield-defense"]
    sword_DMG = users[str(user.id)]["sword-DMG"]
    stage = users[str(user.id)]["stage"]

    defense_percent = (1 + (guardians / 10)) + (shield / 2) - (((shield_durability * -1) + 100) / 10) - (hunger)
    power_percent = (1 + (mages / 10)) + (sword / 2) - (((sword_durability * -1) + 100) / 10) - (hunger)
    luck_percent = (1 + (hunters / 10)) + (armor / 2) - (((armor_durability * -1) + 100) / 10) - (hunger)

    if defense_percent <= 0:
        defense_percent = 0
    if power_percent <= 0:
        defense_percent = 0
    if luck_percent <= 0:
        defense_percent = 0

    defense = defense_percent * defense + shield_defense
    power = power_percent * power + sword_DMG
    defense = round(defense)
    power = round(power)

    hp = 100
    hp = hp + defense

    hp_enemy = 100
    power_enemy = 50

    e = discord.Embed(title=names[stage] + " - " + str(stage) + ". stage",color=3447003)
    e.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/Fu0Ra1W.png")
    e.add_field(name="Your statistics", value="```" + str(hp) + " HP " + str(power) + " DMG ```", inline=False)
    e.add_field(name="Enemy statistics", value="```" + str(hp_enemy) + " HP " + str(power_enemy) + " DMG ```", inline=False)
    e.set_footer(text="g tutorial tower")
    message_embed = await msg.send(embed=e)

    def checkyn(message):
        return message.content in ["a", "h", "p", "d"]

    enemy_attack = random.randint(0, power_enemy)
    hp -= enemy_attack
    message_enemy_attack = await msg.send("Enemy hit you for " + str(enemy_attack) + " DMG.")
    await message_embed.edit(embed=e)
    if hp <= 0:
        await msg.send(msg.author.mention + "** Battle has ended.** You have lost.")
        users[str(msg.author.id)]["battle-active"] -= 1
        with open("rpg.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        return
    while True:
        answer = await bot.wait_for("message", check=checkyn)
        while True:
            if answer.author.id == msg.author.id:
                break
        if answer.content == "a":
            player_attack = random.randint(0, power)
            hp_enemy -= player_attack
            await answer.delete()
            await message_embed.edit(embed=e)
            if hp_enemy <= 0:
                await msg.send(msg.author.mention + "** Battle has ended.** You have won and defeated the stage.")
                users[str(msg.author.id)]["battle-active"] -= 1
                with open("rpg.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(users, f)
                return
        enemy_attack = random.randint(0, power_enemy)
        hp -= enemy_attack
        await message_enemy_attack.edit(content="Enemy hit you for " + str(enemy_attack) + " DMG.")
        await message_embed.edit(embed=e)
        if hp <= 0:
            await msg.send(msg.author.mention + "** Battle has ended.** You have lost.")
            users[str(msg.author.id)]["battle-active"] -= 1
            with open("rpg.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(users, f)
            return
````

Comment: What exactly happens? Any errors/tracebacks? What are the files causing the errors? Or the bot simply does not edit the message?

Comment: No, there are no errors, no files causing the problem and the bot edit the messages normally. But in embed message as you can see, HP should be updated every time the enemy hit the player. But updating the value in embed message doesnt work for some reason. It works fine with normal message under the embed one. For example when enemy hits the player for 10 DMG, the message gets updated on ´Enemy hit you for 10 DMG´, so the embed message should be updated on ´97 HP 12 DMG´ and so on.

Comment: How did you define `rpg_data` and `open_rpg`?